# In Java how to find random factors of a given number

Tags: java

I have a given number. How can I find the factors of that number (for example, 5 and 3 for the number 15)?  Here is the code I tried:

```
int factor1 = 2;

while ((a % factor1 != 0) && (a >= factor1)) {
    d++;
}

if (factor1 == a){
    d = 1;
}
```

But this gives me only the smallest factor (i.e a=3 all the time). I would like to get a random set of factors.

Comment: They are called **"factors"** rather than "multiples". Knowing that, I'm sure you can research this question.

Comment: You are looking for the factors of the number, not the multiples. A multiple of 15 would be 30, 45, 60 etc. One other comment, when checking for the factors of a number, you only need to check the values between 1 (Always ) a factor, and the number/2, as the minimum number of times a number can go into another is 2 (Excluding decimals).

Comment: Or "divisors", which is more closely associated with the OP's wrong term "multiples".  "Factors" has connotations of "prime factors", however, which may or may not be what the OP *really* wants.

Comment: @Aparna, what do you mean you want a *random* set of results?  That would be possible, but quite odd.  Ordinarily, one would want *all* of the divisors, or maybe just all of them that are prime numbers (i.e. the "prime factors").

Comment: Thankyou for the answers...I wanted the factors to be generated randomly because I was making a division game and wanted random division questions below a given number like 20 etc. Hence wanted random factors. I guess I will have to store all the factors in an array and pick them randomly.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through each number from 1 to N inclusively using the modulus operator (`%`). If `n%currentNumber==0`, they are a factor. Below, I did this using a `for` loop, outputting each factor as it is found.

```
    int number=15;
    for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++){
        if(number%i==0){
            System.out.println("Found factor: " + i);
        }
    }
```

As Theo said in a comment on this post, you can also use `number/2`, and arbitrarily include 1 and `number`.

```
    int number=2229348;
    System.out.println("Found factor: " + 1);
    for(int i = 2; i <= number/2; i++){
        if(number%i==0){
            System.out.println("Found factor: " + i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Found factor: " + number);
```

Comment: Why not use number/2? There will be no integer factors with a value over 1/2 of the original number.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 read his question, it's clearly asking for factors. He used the incorrect word. Not to mention, it was now edited to be correct.

Comment: SamTebbs33- Actually, the original poster was asking for factors. And has since edited their answer to say 'divisors'.

Comment: @TheoPearson-Bray Good point. Updated my answer to include both options.

Comment: @MikeElofson Ah ok, I have removed the original comment and the downvote.

Comment: @MikeElofson You should probably edit the second code snippet to print "factor" rather than "multiple"

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the numbers from `2` to `a/2` and check if the given number divides `a`, which is done using the `%` operator:

```
int a = 15;
System.out.print("Divisors of " + a + ": ");
for(int i = 2; i <= a/2; ++i) {
    if(a % i == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

This code prints all of the **divisors** of `a`. Not that you most probably want to ignore `1`, since it divides all integers. Moreover, you don't need to check the numbers until `a`, because no number bigger than `a / 2` can actually divide `a` apart from `a` itself.

Comment: You should edit the print statement to print "factors" rather than "multiples"

Answer (score 0):

The while loop with default values of a=15 and multiple=2 is already in an infinite loop. You need to correct that and check for subsequent increments of multiple whenever a%multiple ! = 0

public class Factors {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    /**
    int multiple1=2,d=0,a=15; //multiple to be rephrased as factor

    while((a%multiple1 != 0)&&(a>=multiple1)){
        multiple1++; //this will increment the factor and check till the number itself
        //System.out.println(multiple1+" is not a factor of a");

    }
    if(multiple1==a){
        d=1;
    }
     *commented the original code
     */ 


    int factor=1,d=0,a=20; //multiple rephrased as factor

    while(a/2>=factor){  //re-arranged your while condition
        factor++;
        if((a%factor==0))
                d++;      //increment factor count whenever a factor is found
    }

    System.out.println("Total number of factors of a : "+(d+2)); // 1 and 'a' are by default factors of number 'a'
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To find all factors inlcuding 1 and the number itself you can do something like below:

```
//Iterate from 2 until n/2 (inclusive) and divide n by each number.
//Return numbers that are factors (i.e. remainder = 0). Add the number itself in the end.
int[] findAllFactors(int number) {
  int[] factors = IntStream.range(1, 1 + number / 2).filter(factor -> number % factor == 0).toArray();
  int[] allFactors = new int[factors.length+1];
  System.arraycopy(factors,0,allFactors,0,factors.length);
  allFactors[factors.length] = number;
  return allFactors;
}
```

To find only prime factors you can do something like this:

```
//Iterate from 2 until n/2 (inclusive) and divide n by each number.
// Return numbers that are factors (i.e. remainder = 0) and are prime
int[] findPrimeFactors(int number) {
  return IntStream.range(2, 1 + number/ 2).filter(factor -> number % factor == 0 && isPrime(factor)).toArray();
}
```

Helper method for primality check:

```
//Iterate from 2 until n/2 (inclusive) and divide n by each number. Return false if at least one divisor is found
boolean isPrime(int n) {
 if (n <= 1) throw new RuntimeException("Invalid input");
 return !IntStream.range(2, 1+n/2).filter(x -> ((n % x == 0) && (x != n))).findFirst().isPresent();
}
```

If you are not on Java 8 and/or not using Lambda expressions, a simple iterative loop can be as below:

```
//Find all factors of a number
public Set<Integer> findFactors(int number) {
    Set<Integer> factors = new TreeSet<>();
    int i = 1;
    factors.add(i);
    while (i++ < 1 + number / 2) {
      if ((number % i) == 0) {
        factors.add(i);
      }
    }
    factors.add(number);
    return factors;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Abc{
public static void main(String...args){
    if(args.length<2){
        System.out.println("Usage : java Abc 22 3");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    int no1=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int no=Integer.parseInt(args[1]),temp=0,i;
    for(i=no;i<=no1;i+=no){
        temp++;
    }

    System.out.println("Multiple of "+no+" to get "+no1+" is :--> "+temp);
    //System.out.println(i+"--"+no1+"---"+no);
    System.out.println("Reminder is "+(no1-i+no));
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can give more insight into what your code is doing and explain it. This code is actually incorrect and will not give the factors of a number which is what the asker wants.